# Python: data type conversion of numpy array containing NaN

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, integer, nan

I am incurring in a behaviour that I cannot comprehend.

### Problem description

I was hoping that trying to convert the data type of an array to integer would raise the "classic" `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` when the array contains NaN.
This unfortunately does not happen.

At a first glance this seems not happening because the NaN contained in a numpy array are converted to `numpy.float64` instead of "remaining" `float` as per [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) documentation.

In fact, consider this example:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([np.nan, 1])

print(type(arr[0]))      # Output: <class 'numpy.float64'>


# Converting numpy.float64 NaN to other data types

## numpy integers
print( np.int8(arr[0]))  # Output: 0 
print(np.int32(arr[0]))  # Output: 0
print(np.int32(arr[0]))  # Output:          -2147483648 (i.e. -2 ** 31)
print(np.int64(arr[0]))  # Output: -9223372036854775808 (i.e. -2 ** 63)

## numpy unsigned integers
print( np.uint8(arr[0]))  # Output: 0
print(np.uint16(arr[0]))  # Output: 0
print(np.uint32(arr[0]))  # Output: 0
print(np.uint64(arr[0]))  # Output: 9223372036854775808

## numpy floats
print(np.float16(arr[0]))  # Output: NaN
print(np.float32(arr[0]))  # Output: NaN
print(np.float64(arr[0]))  # Output: NaN


# Converting numpy.float NaN to other data types

## np.float and np.int are aliases to float and int respectively (both np.float and np.int are deprecated)
type(np.nan) == type(np.float(np.nan))  # Output: True
print(np.int(np.nan))                   # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

## numpy integers
print( np.int8(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print(np.int16(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print(np.int32(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print(np.int64(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

## numpy unsigned integers
print( np.uint8(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print(np.uint16(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print(np.uint32(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
print(np.uint64(np.nan))  # Output: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

## numpy floats
print(np.float16(np.nan))  # Output: NaN
print(np.float32(np.nan))  # Output: NaN
print(np.float64(np.nan))  # Output: NaN
```

### Questions

- Why the elements of `arr` are converted to `numpy.float64` instead of `float` in the first place?
- In what exactly do python built-in `float` and `numpy.float64` differ?
- Why `np.int32(arr)` and `np.int64(arr)` contain the "smallest possible int" while `np.int8(arr)` and `np.int16(arr)` contain zeros? (Similar question for unsigned integer types)

### Edit

I am experiencing this behaviour on multiple platform/python/numpy versions, see the three examples below.

```py
import platform
import sys
import numpy
print('Platform:', platform.platform())
print('Python version:', sys.version)
print('numpy.__version__:', numpy.__version__)
```

#### WSL

```py
Platform: Linux-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
Python version: 3.9.7 (default, Mar  3 2022, 13:49:04) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
numpy.__version__: 1.21.5
```

#### Windows

```py
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22593-SP0
Python version: 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
numpy.__version__: 1.21.0
```

#### Online [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_default)

```py
Platform: Linux-4.19.0-18-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
Python version: 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
numpy.__version__: 1.18.2
```

Comment: I'll only be able to take a closer look later but there's at least one red herring: `np.float is float`, a deprecated alias. If you want numpy, use `np.float_`.

Comment: You actually pointed that out in a comment so I'm not sure why you brought that up in the first place.

Comment: I pointed that out to explicitly show it (`type(np.nan) == type(np.float(np.nan))`) because there may be people not aware of it. Also, in this way I stress out that the following lines use NaN defined as `float`, as opposite to the lines above where NaN is `np.float64`.

Comment: This seems related [to this recent bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21166). Looks like some of those numbers can indeed be platform-dependent too.

Comment: Thank you @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, I had just posted an issue on the github numpy page. Exactly 2 minutes before your comment.